# How do I tell typescript to infer part of an object's type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Is there a way to tell TypeScript to infer the type of part of an object?
Here I'm using [index: string], but then I don't get intellisense when I type `registryObject.partOfTheObject.`

I can't let the type for the whole object be inferred(by not setting a type on it), because I am using mapped types, etc for other parts of it.

```
interface RegistryObject {
    partOfTheObject: {
        [index: string]: {
            [index: string]: Keybind;
        }
    }
}

let myRegistry: RegistryObject = {
    partOfTheObject: {
        someStuff: {
            a: new Keybind("a"),
            b: new Keybind("b"),
            c: new Keybind("c"),
        },
        someMoreStuff: {
            Z: new Keybind("Z"),
            Y: new Keybind("Y"),
            X: new Keybind("X"),
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can make your inferred object type compatible with mapped types. Inference is pretty much the ideal way to go here. Can you post more of your code, particularly where you are using mapped types?

Comment: Just wrap your object into function. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/WKVQMm). In such cases you need to infer the object

Comment: @jered
```
textures: {
 item: {
  [ID in ItemID]: HTMLImageElement
 } | {};
 building: {
  [ID in RawBuildingID]: HTMLImageElement
 } | {};
}
```
I'm not too familiar with mapped types, they might be the solution here.

Comment: @captain-yossarian that is one of the weirdest hacks I've seen so far
but it works

Comment: @BalaM314 this is how it works in typescript. In order to infer smth you should use function, otherwise, you can just get rid of explicit type `RegistryObject` from `myRegistry`